# In an app with a left sidebar for navigation and a hideable right sidebar for contextual info, how contextual should it be?

Tags: sidebar

Our navigation sidebar is on the left. We also have this right-hand sidebar to provide contextual info based on the feature that a user is looking at. Within a given feature, Cohorts in this screenshot, there are three subpages where the sidebar is shown: when viewing the list of created cohorts, when creating a new cohort, and when viewing a created cohort.

[image: Sidebar example]

Currently, it displays the same sidebar content regardless of whether you're viewing the list, creating one, or viewing a created one–it's general info about cohorts in the product. Because the content displayed is somewhat different depending on the subpage you're on, I'm considering tailoring the sidebar content to be even more contextual depending on on which of these three sub-pages you're looking at.

Is it better to keep the right info sidebar consistent (i.e. the same content on the list page, create page, and view page)? Or is making it even more contextual better UX?

Comment: In this case, the right sidebar is related to the first card with Lorem Ipsum title?

Comment: @Devin The right sidebar includes general info about the cards in the center of the screen, so it'd include an overview that discusses both cards in this screenshot, but it wouldn't necessarily go into the nitty-gritty of a chart you might see in the second card.